# TypeError: Cannot read property 'state name in much object' of undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I tried a bunch of object for some state stuff, lets say this was in this.state:

```
this.state = {
 musicinmedia: {
  isDetected: false,
  metadata: {
   songname: '',
   artistname: '',
   albumname: '',
  }
 }
}
```

and this in render:

```
{this.state.musicinmedia.metadata.songname}
```

and gave me an error of:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'songname' of undefined`

Comment: Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your current code snippet does not have any issues that would give rise to the error you got. The error you got indicates `this.state.musicinmedia.metadata` is `undefined` but that is not the case in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your state might not be initialized, so you need to handle a null/undefined value until it is. You could do something like this to make sure state exists.

```
{this.state && this.state.musicinmedia.metadata.songname}
```